# How to get only failed documents in the response from Elasticsearch Java High-Level Client 6.8

Tags: java, elasticsearch, bulkinsert, resthighlevelclient, elasticsearch-rest-client

Is there any way to get only failed documents in the response while bulk request using Elasticsearch Java High-Level REST Client.

Currently, ES is sending all the succeed and failed document in the response and we are reprocessing all the failed document, we are iterating `BulkItemResponse` to find the failed document and reprocessing it.

```
private BulkRequest createBulkRequestsForRetry(BulkResponse bulkItemResponses, BulkRequest currentBulkRequest) {
        BulkRequest bulkRequest = new BulkRequest();
        int index = 0;
        for (BulkItemResponse bulkItemResponse : bulkItemResponses.getItems()) {
            if (bulkItemResponse.isFailed()) {
                bulkRequest.add(currentBulkRequest.requests().get(index));
            }
            index++;
        }
        return bulkRequest;
    }
```

As `bulkItemResponse.getItems()` representing each action performed in the bulk operation (in the same order!).

Answer (score 2):

As of now even in the latest 7.7 version of the client, this feature is not present, if you want this feature you can create an issue or better submit a PR addressing the issue, it would be a very useful feature to have.

You can have a look at the [complete BulkResponse](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/bulk/BulkResponse.java) and see yourself there is no such functionality present in the master branch as well.

Also [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues) you can create an issue to Elasticsearch.

Comment: Agreed. Doc says "To return only information about failed operations, use the `filter_path` query parameter with an argument of `items.*.error.`" but this applies only to the REST API as this filter_path option is not exposed in the REST Client. See also https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/53846

Comment: @dadoonet wow great to hear from Developer Evangelist at Elastic :) and thanks for providing the link for an existing issue, went through and quite useful why it was not implemented.

Comment: I just added my thoughts to the issue :)

Comment: @dadoonet you added a lot more clarity.